# Saving new document as label name in word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

For a project I have to produce many word documents with individual performance reports. I already have the macro that creates these individual reports. What I want now is a macro that uses the value of a created label (E.g. I want the document to have the name of the label "username") which is in the document. I'm afraid that I can't provide code as I didn't get any further than the "save as" command (which is rather easy). Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by 'label name'? can you show a screen shot of it?

Comment: Can't post images yet I'm afraid. Here is the link: (http://imageshack.com/a/img853/2126/nc1j.jpg). Censored the data for privacy purposes. Hope this makes it more clear to you. I made labels in order to easily use data from excel sheets in the word document (I can easily refer to these labels).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the label captions from your Userform to generate a file name and then save the document as the file name?

I would assume then,  that you then passed the Label Captions to the Userform from your Module. if this is the case then you just add then Label Caption string together and then used `ActiveDocument.SaveAs`. see Below:

```
Sub SomeSub()


Dim NewFileName As String


'Do something

'Do something else

'Create and send labels

'Now you would have created the captions for your labels
'and then sent them to the labels

'Just add the various captions

EmailKontact = "someemail@email.com"

Code = "2323"

CaptureDate = "2015.09.21"

NewFileName = EmailKontact & Code & CaptureDate

'For this example
'NewFileName is then = someemail@email.com23232105.09.21

'if you want to save it somewhere specific then you can add
'the folder paths to the NewFileName otherwise is will save it to My Documents

ActiveDocument.SaveAs (NewFileName)


End Sub
```

You could also insert this code to a `CommandButton` label "Save As" in your Userform and then it will as the `ActiveDocument`.